# Postgres DB is taking up a lot of space because of pg_largeobject

Tags: corda

I have my node on Corda 3.0 configured to connect Postgres DB 9.6 on Azure. When I uploaded ~5000 LinearStates (no attachment), it seems that the DB is taking up to ~5GB.

And upon investigation, it seems there's a table `pg_largeobject` that gets populated for every transaction performed. And this table is linked to

1. `node_attachments`
2. `node_checkpoints`
3. `node_identities`
4. `node_message_retry`
5. `node_our_key_pairs`
6. `node_info_party_cert`

Why is the table taking such a large space? Is it normal for this behavior? Even when I switched to H2, the behavior remains? What can contribute to this large data?

Comment: Can you add the Corda version please?

Comment: Added the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Corda bug which will be fixed with 
https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3577/commits/9efa7ac63a38b0d888da29c79cef032d84708184

Answer (score 0):

Package your contract- and state-code in a separate jarfile conform [this structure](https://docs.corda.net/writing-a-cordapp.html#structure):

The contract- and state-code is used for tx-verification and therefore stored in the DB so it should be packaged in a small jar-file.

Comment: The project already follows the exact structure. its 2MB for contract-states.jar